# Grouping in CSS attribute selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Are these equivalent:-

```
selector[attr1="val1"] [attr2="val2"] {
  property: value;
}
```

Select a {selector} which has a attribute called [attr1] that has the exact value of "val1", AND also the same {selector} which has a attribute called [attr2] that has the exact value of "val2". Since the logical operator is "AND", any one condition being wrong will make the selector fail.

```
selector[attr1="val1"], selector[attr2="val2"] {
 property: value;
}
```

This one uses grouping. Can I assume the same for the later as I did for the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the comma is more like an OR, it will select targets with either attribute 1 or attribute 2 or both

Comment: p, h1 {color: red;} - select "p" AND "h1"?

Comment: This will make "p" AND "h1" = color:red?

Comment: Yes, read http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorgrouping, it will affect both of them, it is a logical OR

Comment: If it was a logical AND it would only affect elements that were **both** `p` and `h1` (which is not valid anyway)